# Is it possible to have a Hybrid of Type-Checking (PropTypes & TypeScript) in a React App?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

My Team and I are about to embark on developing a new Front End App. **Myself, I'm coming from Angular.** I read on the [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/docs/static-type-checking.html) site that if our codebase is going to be substantial, it is recommended to do TypeScript or Flow.

My question is, is it possible and/or wise to create an app that uses `PropTypes` for it's **Components** and additionally utilizes `TypeScript` for State Management, **Redux**?

Comment: I really wanna help but why you don't examine it. I cannot understand why you ask this question while you can write it and test it.

Comment: I am trying to find out if others have done it and their experience in maintaining it. I am still going to build the POC, but with the people's info I can figure out the `gotchas`.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do that as they both serve different purposes.

PropTypes are for Run-time type checking and would help you in catching issues after the application is running.

If you want Static Type checking which could help you in identifying issues during the coding phase, then you need Flow or TypeScript.

Flow is simple and can be used without having to learn a new language, but Typescript brings lot more to the project.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and your response!

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's not wise to mix the two, as in, have your static type checking done by both. So if you'd have your state management in `TypeScript`, there is no benefit in not having your components in TSX.

Using `TypeScript` doesn't stop you from using `PropTypes`, but makes it mostly redundant. `PropTypes` allows you to still do some runtime checking or validating, so can still be done even if you chose for TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and your response!

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be highly opinionated, but most of it is not my own opinions.

## PropTypes & Typescript

The two are different.

### Typescript

- A fully fledged type-checking solution.
- Static.
- The main pain point is that there can be so many missing/wrong definitions, want it or not you will spend (quite) some time figuring out why things don't work. It has got A LOT better in the recent year or so, but it is never problem free. For more insight, see, for example, [MUI guide for typescript](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/).
- In addition, Typescript can result in code that is more verbose or complex. See, for instance. [Redux Tool Kit Typescript guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript/)

### PropTypes

PropTypes is far lighter than Typescript in what it can do. And although you can have all sorts of complex validations - most practical usage includes the component props and possibly key structures.

PropTypes can run in run-time, but is often disabled. The benefit of having type-checking in run time is questionable:

- What can you catch in run-time that won't be caught in compile-time?
- What do you do if there are errors?

The general wisdom vector points at this:

> There is no point having both.

## Typescript vs Flow

Although my C++ background made the introduction of type-checking into JavaScript a blessing, I was a huge opponent of TypeScript (having used it for years) and a big supporter of Flow. This was based on many many factors.

### Flow is all but dead

But all that changed in a day, when [Babel Typescript Preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript) become fit for purpose.

What this allows is simply having a hybrid JS/TS project, which means you can:

- Start JS and slowly migrate to TS.
- Start TS and fallback on JS if there are Typescript issues slowing you down.

Sure you could have done it before (and you still have to have Typescript doing the type-checking), but with Babel-Typescript it's hard to think why would you NOT do it.

This has also changes the justification for using Flow in many ways, and topped this with all sorts of issues the Flow team has admitted, Babel-Typescript is left as a very obvious 1st choice for many.

With such a hybrid project, we use Typescript for TSX and PropTypes for JSX.

## Conclusion

So my recommendation would be to set things up with Babel-Typescript to do the compilation and Typescript to do the type-checking only.

If you are to use [NextJs](https://nextjs.org/), for example, all this already comes out of the box. Pretty much nothing for you to do.

Then write a JS/TS hybrid. If velocity you're after, use JS. If type-safety you're after - TS.

The last thing I should mention is that TypeScript inference engine has improved a great deal lately. We actually have many ts/tsx files *with no explicit typing* yet Typescript complains when you are missing a declared prop.

So unless Typescript gives you trouble, you can always start with ts/tsx by default, not type anything (inference will catch issues), then progressively type your code base. If there are Typescript troubles - change to js and solve these later.